# What is the "size" of a quantum particle after decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, decoherence

The volume of a region of space in which a quantum particle will be detected as a result of measurement depends on the laboratory measuring instrument. How does this happen in nature? After decoherence, as a result of interaction with the environment, the density matrix describing the quantum particle turns out to be diagonal in the coordinate basis. What is the volume of a region of space corresponds to each diagonal element? Or does it depend on the environment? Or is the density matrix diagonalizing, describing not one particle, but the entire system of particles (the entire observable universe or a rather large microscopic region)?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason for the downvote, but the question does make one problematic statement: "After decoherence, as a result of interaction with the environment, the density matrix describing the quantum particle turns out to be diagonal in the coordinate basis." That's not quite correct. The density matrix for the particle turns out to be *approximately* diagonal in the coordinate basis, not exactly diagonal. Roughly speaking, the volume that you're asking about is encoded in the "width" of the diagonal-ish ridge in the resulting density matrix.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly And what is the "width" of this ridge?

Comment: The numeric value of the width depends on things like the resolution of the measuring equipment (if the measurement is deliberate) or the environment (if the "measurement" is not deliberate), like you suggested in the question.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Thanks for the answer. Is there any maximum "width"? For example, in a environment with a very small number of low-energy photons.

Comment: There is no upper bound on how big the width can be, because there is no limit on how bad the resolution of a "measurement" can be. The extreme case is if the electron isn't interacting with anything at all, in which case its natural single-particle dispersion will cause the width to grow without bound. The wavelength of the environment-photons is important, too, like you said. Photons of extremely long wavelength can't resolve the electron's location very well.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly As far as I remember, a small particle of dust in deep space, far from large photon sources, still rapidly undergoes decoherence, thanks to the CMB photon bath.

Comment: That's correct, because the typical wavelength of CMB photons is $\sim 1$ millimeter, so they resolve the object's location with a resolution of $\sim 1$ millimeter. So if you're asking about an upper bound on the width of the diagonal in the real universe with the real CMB, then $\sim 1$ millimeter would be typical, but theoretically we can change that by shielding the object from the CMB.